# Handlebars - Backbone Access nested attributes

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

Lets consider I have a model with the following nested structure:

```
article
 >title
 >id
 >related //which is an array lets say of a size n
  >related[0]
  >related[1]
   >title
   >id
```

Is there a way to access each title of the related array by handlebars?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  If you're just looking for a single value then it's just {{article.related.[*n*].title}}.  If you're looking to iterate through them and make a table or something, then you could do:

```
{{#each article.related}}
    {{title}} / {{id}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, could You please give me a link for a documentation where are those kind of examples about Handlebars?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Handlebars site only covers basic usage scenarios.  For things like how to access an array by index, I had to learn the hard way by Googling, pulling my hair out and, like you, asking _lots_ of questions on SO.  That particular tip I learned on SO last month.

Comment: Another good resource, although it isn't documentation, is http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/ where you can try out code live in the browser.